# Does subtracting two Integer objects result in an Integer or a primitive int?

Tags: java, wrapper

Say we have two Integer objects:

```
Integer i=100,j=200;
```

Does `(j-i)` evaluate to another Integer Wrapper object with value 100, or a primitive `int`?

Comment: Why don't you run it through a debugger? Also, prefer primitives to their wrapper equivalents...

Comment: Why wouldn't you try it yourself and see? You could have answered your own question in the same time (or less) that it took to ask it here.

Comment: Because everytime I ask, I learn something new... for example the way SeanA did it, I hadn't thought about it in that way. Sharing knowledge isn't a bad thing after all. In that way everything can be found in some book or the other in this world, so what's the point of this site?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quick test shows that java is using an Integer cache, and re-uses the `i`:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    Integer i=100, j=200;
    System.out.println("i: " + System.identityHashCode(i));
    System.out.println("j: " + System.identityHashCode(j));

    Integer sub = j-i;
    System.out.println("j-i: " + System.identityHashCode(sub));
}
```

Outputs:

```
i: 1494824825
j: 109647522
j-i: 1494824825 <-- same as i
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You helped to clear a lot of doubts I had in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

The result will be an `int` 100.

Both `i` and `j` will be auto-unboxed so the result of `i-j` will be an `int`.

But if you assign the result to as follows:

```
Integer r = i - j;
```

then the result will be auto-boxed again.